# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError in PostsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It was working perfectly fine but now I'm getting this error for some reason?

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
 geocoded_by :address
 after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :users, through: :rsvps

end
```

form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :date %>
    <%= form.datetime_select :date, id: :post_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_area :name, id: :post_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="action">
    <%= form.label :address %>
    <%= form.text_area :address, id: :post_address %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.number_field :user_id, id: :post_user_id, value: current_user.id %>

  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description, id: :post_description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

post controller

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
     @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
   unless current_user == @post.user
    redirect_back fallback_location: root_path, notice: 'User is not owner'
   end
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end



  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:date, :user_id, :description, :name, :address)
    end
    load_and_authorize_resource


end
```

migrations

```
class AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToPost < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
      def change
        add_column :posts, :latitude, :float
        add_column :posts, :longitude, :float
        add_column :posts, :address, :string
      end
    end
```

posts migration

```
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.datetime :date
      t.string   :name
      t.integer :user_id
      t.text :description


      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm not sure how it would stop working automatically as there was literally no changes. I was just figuring out why my google static map was getting an error. However I didn't implement any changes so I don't know what could have possibly caused this error? I would appreciate some advice, thank you.

Comment: can you restart the server ?

Comment: Your code seems ok, I don't see any problem

Comment: Can you post the entire error message and the first few lines of the stack trace?

Comment: do you already use git? If so and if you are committing regularly you can use `git diff` to see your changes. Otherwise, this is a good time to start using git.

Comment: public_send("#{k}=", v)
        else
          raise UnknownAttributeError.new(self, k)
        end
      end
  end

Comment: and i do use git, there was also no difference either...

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError` is when you try to assign an attribute which is not present in the table.

You must have added some attributes to `Post` model but must have forgotten to run the migration

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Running this command should solve the problem

**NOTE**: I can see there is a new migration `AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToPost` which is adding some columns to `posts` table. Check the migration status with:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:status
```

Check if you can see same attributes in `schema.rb`

Comment: I tried running the command and I'm still getting the same error. Also I do not have the same attributes in the post table when I check my schema

Comment: Alright I've checked the migration status it says "up" which I'm assuming is correct because it says the for all my migrations

Comment: thank you but I fixed the problem, however I do appreciate your help :)